# osx 10.8.5 - Ruby on Rails - rmagick error on rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rmagick

I'm trying to run a project which uses rmagick, `bundle` is running fine but on `rails s` I get:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Evo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Evo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Evo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle (You may need to install the rmagick gem)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing liblzma dependency? With Homebrew, it’s included in the `xz` forumla. Try `brew install xz`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'd accept this as answer if you post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error indicates you’re missing the dependency on liblzma, which in Homebrew is contained in the xz formula. Try this:

```
brew install xz
```

Comment: I needed to remove the older version `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.0.3` and `brew link --force xz` for Version 5.2.0